# Como passar uma List usando Intent de uma Activity para ou Activity

Tags: android

Preciso passar  `List<Carro> carro` usando `Intent` de uma `Activity` para ou `Activity`.

Carro é uma classe com vários elementos `String modelo, String categoria Double potencia`

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, faça sua classe implementar [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), exemplo:

```
public class Carro implements Serializable{}
```

Na sua intent você faz um cast para serializable:

```
List<Carro> list = new ArrayList<Carro>();
myIntent.putExtra("LIST", (Serializable) list);
```

Na segunda Activity você pode pegar a lista assim:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
list = (List<Carro>) i.getSerializableExtra("LIST");
```

Existe formas mais performáticas de passar parâmetros entre acitivities usando [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: E extremamente recomendado usar Parcelable, já que uma lista pode ser grande, considere usar uma Asynctask para executar o putExtra ou getSerializableExtra.